# How avoid of using same table at same time in database with different functions

Tags: android, service, android-sqlite

I have a database in my application and I have a service that is working in the background all the time (when the app is running or not).

in service and some activities of Application exists functions that read and write into database tables. sometimes I have crashed in my app because it is possible that more than one function start to access to the same table!
And I am using an external database.(I have a database in my asset folder and first of all, I will copy it into SD Card and going to use it).
till now I did disable service when the app was open but I need service to be run all the time.

UPDATE: Code Added:
This is my code that how I access to my database:

```
 //Creating folder for database in SD Card!
    new File(G.DIR_APP).mkdirs();
    File file = new File(G.DIR_APP, "database.sqlite");

    if (file.exists()) {
      //Do nothing
    } else {
      /*
      *
      * This part will start when db file is not exist on it's place
      * or
      * Deleted
      * or
      * ...
      *
       */
      try {

        AssetManager assetManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream;
        inputStream = assetManager.open("database.sqlite");
        HelperIO.copyFile(inputStream, G.DIR_APP + "database.sqlite");

      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }
```

Here is an method that i use to access my database:

```
private void insertMenuItemsIntoDB(ArrayList<MenuItem> appArray) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(G.DIR_APP + "/database.sqlite", null);

    for (int i = 0; i < appArray.size(); i++) {

      boolean newFile = true;

      ArrayList<MenuItem> bootArray = G.bootAppsFromDB();

      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

      values.put(G.MENU_ITEM_ID, appArray.get(i).getMenuItemId());
      values.put(G.MENU_ITEM_NAME, appArray.get(i).getMenuItemName());
      values.put(G.MENU_ITEM_DESC, appArray.get(i).getMenuItemDesc());
      values.put(G.MENU_ITEM_APP, appArray.get(i).getMenuItemApp());
      values.put(G.MENU_ITEM_PARENT, appArray.get(i).getMenuItemParent());
      values.put(G.MENU_ITEM_START_X, appArray.get(i).getMenuItemStartX());
      values.put(G.MENU_ITEM_START_Y, appArray.get(i).getMenuItemStartY());
      values.put(G.MENU_ITEM_SPAN_X, appArray.get(i).getMenuItemSpanX());
      values.put(G.MENU_ITEM_SPAN_Y, appArray.get(i).getMenuItemSpanY());
      values.put(G.MENU_ITEM_HAS_WIDGET, appArray.get(i).getMenuItemHasWidget());
      values.put(G.MENU_ITEM_WIDGET_ACTIVE, appArray.get(i).getMenuItemWidgetActive());
      values.put(G.MENU_ITEM_DELETED, appArray.get(i).getMenuItemDeleted());
      values.put(G.MENU_ITEM_LAST_CHANGE, appArray.get(i).getMenuItemLastChange());
      values.put(G.MENU_ITEM_PACKAGE_NAME, appArray.get(i).getMenuItemPackagename());

      for (MenuItem menuItem : bootArray) {

        if (menuItem.getMenuItemId().equals(appArray.get(i).getMenuItemId())) {

          newFile = false;

          SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
          String dateDB = menuItem.getMenuItemLastChange();
          String dateServer = appArray.get(i).getMenuItemLastChange();

          try {
            Date dateFromDB = sdf.parse(dateDB);
            Date dateFromServer = sdf.parse(dateServer);

            if (dateFromServer.compareTo(dateFromDB) > 0) {

              db.update(G.DATABASE_TABLE_MENU_ITEM, values, G.MENU_ITEM_ID + "=" + appArray.get(i).getMenuItemId(), null);

              break;
            }
          } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }

      if (newFile == true) { //If newFile = true then this file is new

        db.insert(G.DATABASE_TABLE_MENU_ITEM, null, values);
      }
    }
 }
```

I really appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 3):

I used the singleton pattern and it solved the problem:

```
public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "databaseName";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static SQLiteHelper mInstance;//Singleton Instance

    /**
      * Use the application context, which will ensure that you
      * don't accidentally leak an Activity's context.
      * See this article for more information: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html
     */
    public static synchronized SQLiteHelper getInstance(Context context){
        if(mInstance == null){
            mInstance = new SQLiteHelper(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
}
```

See this article for more information:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in my case, i am using an SQLite database from my asset folder then how can I use this class?

Comment: Please post your code that how are you accessing database

Comment: I added my Codes